# values overwrite numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am quite new to Python. Any help would be appreciated.

`ret_val` is generating 0 or 1 labels and euclidean distance is genreating distance 0.55 or 0.23..

So what i want is to add those values into a numpy array like:

**example**

```
> arr= np.array([[0.55, 0.23], [0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 0.2]])
> arrdist= np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
```

i want to apply it to my code

output of my code should be :

```
[[0.7 0.3]
 [0.4 0.6]
 [0.8 0.2]]
[[1 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]]
```

but output of my code return only the last values [[0]]
[[37.11052]]

When I try to run the code, values overwrite the array i get only the last element added on the array :

```
i = 1
for j in range (1,5):
 ret_val, euclidean_distance = verifyFace(str(i)+"tst.jpg", str(j)+"train.jpg", epsilon)
 if ret_val == '0':
    a = 0
    print(euclidean_distance)

    arr = np.array([[(a)]])

    arrdist = np.array([[(euclidean_distance)]])
 elif ret_val =='1':
    b=1

    arr = np.array([[(b)]])

    arrdist = np.array([[(euclidean_distance)]])

print(arr)
print(arrdist)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar the example is the expected output

Comment: You can check append() method -> https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/python-numpy-exercise-12.php

Hope its help.

Comment: Why don't you just create an empty `list` for `arr_dist` and `arr` and use `.append` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring arr and arrdist outside of your for loop. Initialize them as empty arrays like so:

```
i = 1
arr = []
arrdist = []
for j in range (1,5):
    ...
    if ...:
        ...
        arr.append([a])
        arrdist.append([euclidean_distance])
...
```

after your for loop, you convert your list into a numpy array, if you need a numpy array:

```
arr = np.array(arr)
arrdist = np.array(arrdist)
```